# Menuitem changes very slowly when sliding tab

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am using sliding tabs for MainActivity, for each tab I have different menuitem, everything is working fine but when I slide tabs, menuitem changes very slowly. How can I make it to change quickly? similar to the way Whatsapp is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you taking different menu files for all the three tabs?

Comment: on page change listener hold the value of current position of selected fragment in one variable and apply logic in oncreateoptionmenu(). Inflate menu file according to position.

Comment: I'm not using pageChangeListener, I followed this [link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout)

Comment: MenuItems are showing properly, but only problem is that it take 1-2 sec to show up.

Comment: you can try by creating it dynamically instead of using xml because it can take time but dynamically definitely it ll execute in secnods.